# How to read the specific set elements from an array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, jpgraph

I have this array, I am trying to store the first element(15) in one array(xAxis) and from second element(42) to fifth(23) in another array(yAxis) and again I want to store the sixth element(15) in the array - xAxis and later 4  elements in yAxis. I have more than hundred elements in the source array and want to follow this pattern to store in the arrays.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 15
    [1] => 42
    [2] => 55
    [3] => 42
    [4] => 23
    [5] => 15
    [6] => 38
    [7] => 40
    [8] => 53
    [9] => 10
    [10] => 15
)
```

Thanks.

Comment: So what's stopping you?

Comment: Welcome, please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) I guess what you are really asking is **Do it for me** and my answer is **What are you paying, SO is not a free coding site**

Comment: Use [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with a list of keys you need to get the xAxis values, then use [array_diff_key()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php) to compare your main array with the new xAxis array to get the yAxis array

Answer (score 0):

Use loops :

```
$array = Array
(
    [0] => 15
    [1] => 42
    [2] => 55
    [3] => 42
    [4] => 23
    [5] => 15
    [6] => 38
    [7] => 40
    [8] => 53
    [9] => 10
    [10] => 15
)
$x = {};
$y = {};
$step = 0;
for ($i=0; $i < count($array); $i = $i){
if ($step == 0){
array_push($x, $array[$i]);
$i = $i + 1;
}
else
{
array_push($y, $array[$i]);
array_push($y, $array[$i+1]);
array_push($y, $array[$i+2]);
array_push($y, $array[$i+3]);
$i = $i + 4;
}
}
```

Dont forget to be sure that these steps 1-2-3-4 are possible.
that your array is like 10/15/20 long!
else php will return a (silecent) error.

Answer (score 0):

Split the array to parts of 5 items. Then put them in new arrays

```
$yAxis = array();

foreach(array_chunk($arr,5) as $chunk) {
   $xAxis[] = array_shift($chunk);
   $yAxis = array_merge($yAxis, $chunk);
}
```